# how to authenticate with several bases with ldap_devise_authenticatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ldap, openldap

Need to do a search on several bases in OpenLDAP, the problem is that I can make the query to authenticate only one base at a time.

my ldap.yml

```
development:
host: xxxxx
port: 389
attribute: uid
base: ou=Students,dc=fga,dc=unb,dc=br
ssl: false
```

Also would like to know on what basis am getting the parameter?

Example: I have 1 student base and a base servers, would like to add a role to them using cancan, so do: If he finds on the basis of students add

```
before_save :get_ldap_base

def get_ldap_base
self.base = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"base")
end
```

so could add the student paper to it (use to access level using devise + cancan).

my devise.rb

```
config.ldap_create_user = true
```

gem  : gem "devise_ldap_authenticatable"